# How to properly prototype JS sub-pseudoclasses?

Tags: javascript, prototype, pseudo-class

Making subclases is easy. I just follow this structure:

```
var Car = function(x){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = 10;
};
Car.prototype.say_position = function(){
    console.log("("+this.x+", "+this.y+")");
}
var a = new Car(2);
a.say_position(); //(2, 10)
```

Using prototype for classes is good for performance as every instance doesn't have the method repeated. For making subclasses I followed the convention explained here: https://www.udacity.com/course/object-oriented-javascript--ud015
which is as follows:

```
var Car = function(x){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = 10;
}; 
var Van = function(x){
    Car.apply(this, arguments);
};
Van.prototype = Object.create(Car); 
Van.prototype.constructor = Car;
```

Meanwhile, when I try to use prototyped methods with this structure...

```
var Car = function(x){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = 10;
}; 
var Van = function(x){
    Car.apply(this, arguments);
};
Van.prototype = Object.create(Car); 
Van.prototype.constructor = Car;
Car.prototype.say_position = function(){
    console.log("("+this.x+", "+this.y+")");
}


var car = new Car(2);
car.say_position(); //(2, 10)

var van = new Van(2);
van.say_position(); //Error!
```

As you can see, when calling `say_position()` on van, it throws an error. Shouldn't `Van`'s `prototype` delegate to `Car`'s `prototype` and find that function there? Can anyone explain and solve this?

Comment: No, you are delegating to `Car` instead of `Car.prototype`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that you're having is that the argument to `Object.create` should be `Car.prototype`

Here's working code

```
var Car = function(x){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = 10;
}; 

var Van = function(x){
    Car.apply(this, arguments);
};
Van.prototype = Object.create(Car.prototype); 
Van.prototype.constructor = Car;
Car.prototype.say_position = function(){
    console.log("("+this.x+", "+this.y+")");
}

var car = new Car(2);
car.say_position(); //(2, 10)

var van = new Van(2);
van.say_position(); //(2, 10)
```

The [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Classical_inheritance_with_Object.create()) are always a great reference for these types of issues